# VSIX extension for SSMS - how to add menu item to context menu in results grid?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ssms, vsix

I'm attempting to write an extension for SSMS and I need to add a menu item to the results grid context menu (shown below).

[image]

I have been able to add a menu item to the query window context menu, but I got the xml that defines that from a sample project and I can't find anything that does similar for the results grid.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @jps apologies, wrong tag!